# How to handle a color key in pgfkeys

Tags: color, pgfkeys

I'm trying to use `pgfkeys` to parse the arguments in a set of macros. I need to use some arguments for color. But, I get an error with the `xcolor` package saying that the key I defined is not a valid (undefined) color.

So, what is the correct way to define and handle color keys in `pgfkeys`? Also, if I am doing something wrong with `pgfkeys` (like not following best practices) please advice.

Also, I've seen that using another path may be cumbersome, but I want to have different keys besides the one in `/tikz`. So, if you can advice on solving the problem and keeping a different path that will be nice too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{
  /test/.cd,
  my color/.default=red
}

\newcommand{\makenode}[2][]{
\pgfkeys{/test/.cd,#1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=my color]{#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\makenode{testing}
\makenode[my color=blue]{testing blue}

\end{document}
```

Error:

> ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `my color'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very simple cheat-list:

- `.initial` is for a **value**
- `.default` is for an **action**, declared using `.code`.
- `.style` is for style --- something you can put inside `[]`.

Side mark: `\newcommand` is not necessary in case you have `.code`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10]{standalone}
\pgfkeys{
  /test/.cd,
  my color/.initial=red,
}
\newcommand\makenode[2][]{
    \pgfkeys{/test/.cd,#1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw=\pgfkeysvalueof{/test/my color}]{#2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
    \makenode{testing}
    \makenode[my color=blue]{testing blue}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not necesary"? Can I create the whole node automatically triggering it by the `.code`?

Comment: Yes you can. All you need is replace `\newcommand\cs{}` and `\cs` by `\pgfkeys{cs/.code={}}` and `\pgfkeys{cs}`. So this is just a flavor issue, much like `\def`, `\newcommand`, and `\NewDocumentCommand`